# Playing Flash audio with JavaScript

Tags: audio, flash-javascript-api

I just need some direction on how to go about playing an audio clip on an on click from Javascript.

Comment: See this document on ExternalInterface in ActionScript:  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to talk back and forth from flash to javascript you should use the flash.external.ExternalInterface class and callbacks.

#### Flash as3

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

//Create the javascript "playSound" on the swf object
ExternalInterface.addCallback("playSound", playSound);

//Create our sound object
var sound:Sound = new Sound;
//Load my.mp3 into our sound object
sound:Sound .load(new URLRequest("my.mp3"));

function playSound(){
    sound.play();
}
```

#### HTML Page

```
<script language="javascript">
    var swf;

    //Wait for page load to complete
    window.onload = init;

    //initialize our swf variable where mySWF is the id of the swf object on the page
    function init(){
        swf = document.getElementById("mySWF");
    }

    //call our external function on the swf
    function playSound(){
        swf.playSound();
    }
</script>
```

Forgive me for any errors, the code is untested but should give you the right idea.